# How can I set item count value per coloumn in DataList ItemTemplate?

Tags: asp.net, datalist, itemtemplate

I want to set my DataList control to have only 7 items visible in each column after DataBind.

Let's say' if I have 18 items in the data source; DataList should be rendered as 3 colums.

1st column will have first 7 items.
2nd column will have items from 8 to 15 
3rd column will have items from 16 to 18

How can I set the item count per column for each itemTemplate?

Comment: It seems all answerers have misunderstood your question. I'm looking to do what you want to, but so far it looks like the only way is explicit arithmetic on your number of rows/columns vs. your number of items. Myself, I'm trying to detect when the DataList moves to the next column and it looks like I'm stuck with arithmetic as well.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look onto [`DataList.RepeatColumns`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.repeatcolumns.aspx) property:

```
DataList1.RepeatColumns = 3;
DataList1.RepeatDirection = RepeatDirection.Vertical;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're talking about limiting the rows, which you can do in your datasource before you bind.

If you are binding to a DataSet or a DataTable, you can create a DataView and filter the data to a subset of rows choosing the seven that you wish to display.

Or perhaps you're looking to page your data?  In that case you'll set your DataList's PageSize to 7.  (see this article for more:  https://web.archive.org/web/20211020121644/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/081804-1.aspx)